# how to compile the FFTW benchmark to analyse assembly code

Tags: c, benchmarking, fftw

I want to analyse the assembly code generated (particularly the SIMD instructions) by [FFTW benchmark](http://www.fftw.org/)

My not very expert understanding is to use `-S` with the compilation to produce the .s file for instruction analysis. I am using `./configire --enable-sse2 CFLAGS=-O3 -S`

I get the error

```
unrecognized option: '-S'
```

Kindly comment on how to obtain .s files for instruction analysis for such benchmarks. For simple c files, compiling with `-S` is the obvious option.

Comment: `./configire --enable-sse2 CFLAGS=-O3 -S` -> `./configure --enable-sse2 CFLAGS="-O3 -S"` ?

Comment: @PaulR I got rid of this error but got into another one. If I use `./configure --enable-sse2 --host=x86`, everything runs ok in make and install. However if I use `./configure --enable-sse2 CFLAGS="-O3 -S" --host=x86`, I run into an error during the make, `In file included from timer.c:29:0:
cycle.h:112:1: error: unknown type name ‘timebasestruct_t’
 typedef timebasestruct_t ticks;In file included from timer.c:29:0:
cycle.h:112:1: error: unknown type name ‘timebasestruct_t’
 typedef timebasestruct_t ticks;`

Comment: To be honest I don't think this general approach is going to be fruitful - even if you do manage to get a disassembly it will be hard to read and make sense of, particularly because FFTW tunes the butterflies during plan creation (assuming FFTW_MEASURE or better). Personally I would build a test program for a use case of interest, then run it under a profiler which shows source and disassembly (I use Instruments on OS X for this, but you probably have something similar on whatever your chosen platform is).

Comment: @PaulR thank you for your comment. You are right that during the make and build process, a lot of shared libraries and source will be added so -S approach may not help much.